# RPY2: importr fails with .Renviron

Tags: python, macos, r, ggplot2, rpy2

Here's what should and does happen using `rpy2.robjects.packages.importr` for base R-packages (e.g. `stats`):

```
>>> from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
>>> importr('stats')
<rpy2.robjects.packages.SignatureTranslatedPackage object at 0x7f3810>
```

but with an external package (e.g. `ggplot2`) this is the result:

```
>>> importr('ggplot2')
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'ggplot2'
Error in .Primitive("as.environment")("package:ggplot2") : 
  no item called "package:ggplot2" on the search list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/packages.py", line 100, in importr
    env = _as_env(rinterface.StrSexpVector(['package:'+name, ]))
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in .Primitive("as.environment")("package:ggplot2") : 
  no item called "package:ggplot2" on the search list
```

A complication is that in my home directory I have the file `.Renviron` define my user library location (where, for instance, `ggplot2` libs are), and I have no problems with either of the R-commands `library()` or `require()` using `R` and `Rscript`.  The path looks something like this:

```
R_LIBS_USER="/path/to/my/packages"
```

So my question is why my user-library path excluded from the "search list" `Rpy2` uses?  Or, rather, how do I direct `Rpy2` to look in the `R_LIBS_USER` path as well?

I assume the problem stems from the environment `Rpy2` uses, but my ignorance is high in that regard.

```
R: 2.13.0
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (Mac, 10.6, 64-bit)
```

replicated with

```
Rpy2: 2.1.8, 2.2.1 (dev)
```

*I use R, ggplot2, and python regularly, so any insight is very much welcome.*

Comment: I have no problem with the above, using `rpy2` 2.2.0beta, Python 2.6.1 (System, 32 or 64 bits), and R 2.13 (devel or cran release).

Comment: @chl Do you use .Renviron as well?  I just tried with 2.2.1 and have the same results.  The `setup.py` file and the README are not too much help unfortunately.

Comment: I personally gave up on Rpy a long time ago, in favor of making python write the R Code and using "system" calls instead.  There may be advantages of the Rpy package that I miss because of this, but all-in-all the configuration of Rpy gave me entirely too much trouble to bother with...

Comment: No, sorry I should have said that in my comment. Did you try to set up your R libs directly in Python, e.g. `import os; os.environ["R_LIBS_USER"]="/path/to/my/packages"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, rpy2 is initializing in "vanilla" mode, and this ignores R_LIBS and friends.

```
>>> import rpy2.rinterface 
>>> rpy2.rinterface.get_initoptions()
('rpy2', '--quiet', '--vanilla', '--no-save')
>>>
```

You can use 'rinterface.set_initoptions()' to change those.

For example:

```
import rpy2.rinterface as ri
ri.set_initoptions(('rpy2', '--verbose', '--no-save'))
ri.initr()

# from now on, just import the rest of rpy2 modules without thinking of the above.
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!  One question: do you know how to permanently change the default initializing behavior (so I don't have to repeatedly set_initoptions if I start new python sessions)?

Comment: @andyB: the only way to change the default behaviour is to edit the source code.

Comment: @AndyBarbour one alternative would be to have this code on a module of your own that adds these and other customizations to the rpy2 loading mechanism and then `import mycustomrpy2...`.

Comment: @Unode Good idea; I hadn't thought of that.